# com.liferay.mozilla missing from Liferay API

Tags: api, liferay, mozilla

I need to use some classes from these packages

1. com.liferay.mozilla.javascript.context
2. com.liferay.mozilla

and com.liferay.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject  class but I don't know in which jar they are wrapped in, and of course Liferay support are dead silent.

So if anyone had this problem and has a solution to my problem, please answer me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JAR-file is called "liferay-rhino.jar" but I wasn't able to find it in versions of Liferay Portal after 6.0.6. So you should download it separately if you want to use it in a portlet.

In versions 5.2 and 6.0.6 it's located in folder `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`.